# cast from List<EntityObject> to EntityObject

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My code is as below.

```
public void CreateNewAuthor(List<Author> newAuthor)
{
    publishContext.AddToAuthors(newAuthor);
}
```

I know this will result in error as AddToAuthors(Author newAuthor) accepts entity object as parameter while I am passing a List<>. So how this should be handled? How to cast a List<> to entity object before AddToAuthors()?

Comment: A List is as the name sais a 'list' of objects. So how do you wanna transform for example a list of 10 authors into 1 author?

Comment: perhaps you should rename your variable to `newAuthors`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accepting *multiple* authors - but you're trying to call something which takes a *single* author. Are you expecting multiple values within your list, or just a single one?

It sounds like you *might* just want to loop:

```
public void CreateNewAuthor(List<Author> newAuthors)
{
    foreach (Author newAuthor in newAuthors)
    {
        publishContext.AddToAuthors(newAuthor);
    }
}
```

... or it's entirely possible that the context already provides a way of adding multiple authors at a time. (I'm not an EF person, so I don't know for sure.)

The important thing is that you understand the possibilities here - the list could contain no authors, one author or multiple authors. Are all of those valid in your code? How do you want to handle each of those situations?

Comment: Thnx...Jon. I understood the mistake I was doing. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop trough the list and add all the Author objects this list contains:

```
foreach (Author author in newAuthor)
{
    publishContext.AddToAuthors(author);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1. You know that the list contains only one item:**

1. Change your method's signature to the following:

   ```
   public void CreateNewAuthor(Author newAuthor)
   ```

   (It is very unintuitive to refer to a list of items with a name that is not in the plural. It is even more unintuitive that your method accepts a list of (ie. "several") `Author` objects, yet requires that the list contain only one item.)
2. Then, call your method as follows:

   ```
   // using System.Linq;
   // List<Author> someListOfAuthors = new List<Author> { someAuthor };
   CreateNewAuthor( someListOfAuthors.Single() );
   ```

   or, without using LINQ:

   ```
   CreateNewAuthor( someListOfAuthors[0] );
   ```

**Case 2. The list may contain any number of items:**

1. Rename the parameter from `newAuthor` to `newAuthors`, for the same reason mentioned above.
2. Change your method body to this:

   ```
   foreach (Author author in newAuthors)
   {
       publishContext.AddToAuthors(author);
   }
   ```